# Seeding mongoDB data in node.js by referencing ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, seeding

i'm using [mongoose-data-seed](https://github.com/sharvit/mongoose-data-seed) to seed data into mongodb, however it has no mechanism to allow passing of ObjectId() as references to other seed files

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to store the output of each of the seeders in a json file and retrieve the ObjectIds from the previous seeds to use in the current seeder. This way i can reference ObjectIds from previous seeders.

**seeding-helper.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
// const path = require('path');

const seedersTmpDataFolder = 'seeders/bin';

class SeedingHelper {
  static saveData(filename, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      fs.writeFile(`${seedersTmpDataFolder}/${filename}.json`, JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  static readData(filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      fs.readFile(`${seedersTmpDataFolder}/${filename}.json`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        resolve(JSON.parse(data));
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = SeedingHelper;
```

**resourceActions.seeder.js**

```
const { Seeder } = require('mongoose-data-seed');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ResourceAction = require('../models/resourceAction');
const SeedingHelper = require('../helpers/seeding-helper');

const { Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose;

const data = [
  {
    _id: ObjectId(),
    name: 'test1'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(),
    name: 'test2'
  },
];

class ResourceActionSeeder extends Seeder {
  async shouldRun() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    return ResourceAction.count().exec().then(count => count === 0);
  }

  async run() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    let result;
    await SeedingHelper.saveData('resourceActions', data)
      .then(() => {
        result = ResourceAction.create(data);
      });
    return result;
  }
}

module.exports = ResourceActionSeeder;
```

**resources.seeder.js**

```
const { Seeder } = require('mongoose-data-seed');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Resource = require('../models/resource');
const SeedingHelper = require('../helpers/seeding-helper');

const { Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose;

class ResourcesSeeder extends Seeder {
  async shouldRun() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    return Resource.count().exec().then(count => count === 0);
  }

  async run() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    let result;
    await SeedingHelper.readData('resourceActions')
      .then((resourceActionsData) => {
        const machinesId = ObjectId();

        const actionTest1 = ObjectId(resourceActionsData.find(x => x.name === 'test1')._id);
        const actionTest2 = ObjectId(resourceActionsData.find(x => x.name === 'test2')._id);

        const data = [
          {
            _id: machinesId,
            name: 'machines',
            actions: [
              actionTest1,
              actionTest2,
            ],
          },
        ];

        result = Resource.create(data);

        if (result) SeedingHelper.saveData('resources', data);
      });
    return result;
  }
}

module.exports = ResourcesSeeder;
```